# Seperate Database for flask admin

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

can anyone tell me, how to make a separate Database just for Flask admin and maybe flask security?
this is how i am working with my PostgreSQL database just to load some tables and perform CRUD:

```
import flask_admin
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


app =Flask(__name__)
engine = create_engine{'postgresql://name:password@localhost/tablesdatabase')
```

i wish to make a separate database for flask-admin :( this is what i am trying)

```
admin = flask_admin.Admin(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {'admindb' : 'postgresql://name:password@localhost/adminedatabase'}
admin.add_view(ModelView) ? // how can i impelement this ? with a seperate datbase ?
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no official support, but you can customize Flask-SQLalchemy session to use different connections, here the example for using `master` `slave` connections, you can easily add as many connections as you want

```
from functools import partial

from sqlalchemy import orm
from flask import current_app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, get_state


class RoutingSession(orm.Session):
    def __init__(self, db, autocommit=False, autoflush=True, **options):
        self.app = db.get_app()
        self.db = db
        self._bind_name = None
        orm.Session.__init__(
            self, autocommit=autocommit, autoflush=autoflush,
            bind=db.engine,
            binds=db.get_binds(self.app),
            **options,
        )

    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        try:
            state = get_state(self.app)
        except (AssertionError, AttributeError, TypeError) as err:
            current_app.logger.info(
                'cant get configuration. default bind. Error:' + err)
            return orm.Session.get_bind(self, mapper, clause)

        # If there are no binds configured, use default SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
        if not state or not self.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS']:
            return orm.Session.get_bind(self, mapper, clause)

        # if want to user exact bind
        if self._bind_name:
            return state.db.get_engine(self.app, bind=self._bind_name)
        else:
            # if no bind is used connect to default
            return orm.Session.get_bind(self, mapper, clause)

    def using_bind(self, name):
        bind_session = RoutingSession(self.db)
        vars(bind_session).update(vars(self))
        bind_session._bind_name = name
        return bind_session


class RouteSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SQLAlchemy.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.session.using_bind = lambda s: self.session().using_bind(s)

    def create_scoped_session(self, options=None):
        if options is None:
            options = {}
        scopefunc = options.pop('scopefunc', None)
        return orm.scoped_session(
            partial(RoutingSession, self, **options),
            scopefunc=scopefunc,
        )
```

Than the default session will be `master`, when you want to select from slave you can call it directly, here the examples:

In your app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///master'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'slave': 'postgresql:///slave'
}

db = RouteSQLAlchemy(app)
```

Select from master

```
session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first()
```

Select from slave

```
session.using_bind('slave').query(User).filter_by(id=1).first()
```